# R equivalent of initcap?

Tags: r

When working in Oracle, I quite like the function initcap(), as there are some data fields which are all-caps. Using initcap on these columns makes it much more visually appealing for reports.

The purpose of the function is to go through a vector of strings and make sure that only the first letter of each word is capitalized. Is there an R equivalent of initcap?

Comment: The help file for `?toupper` gives an example function (`.simpleCap`) that should do what you need.

Comment: I don't think `.simpleCap` will work with all caps though will it?

Comment: @user1317221_G: No, but the fix is too trivial to bother with. People need to take some initiative.

Comment: @DWin very true, but I'm in a good mood, `capwords(x, strict=TRUE)`